# How to name an image with the date that it was posted and at the same time being unique?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm saving images to a folder, and I want the image to have as its name, the date when it was post and a way to make it unique, for example using GUID.
I've been using this:

```
 var myfilename = string.Format(@"{0}", Guid.NewGuid()) + ".jpg";
```

and the name that it crates is unique, however I want to add the date. I don't know how to add that to that string.
I also tried just doing:

```
  var myfilename = date + ".jpg";
```

(date is a variable that returns the currant date) but if I use this way, the myfilename variable is null. Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you provide a demo to reproduce this issue? Generally, `myfilename` will be a string, rather than null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var fileName = $"{DateTime.Now.toString()}-{Guid.NewGuid().toString()}.jpg";
```

Comment: It still returns as null

Comment: What is you dare variable value ?

Comment: ocorrencia.DataOcorrencia = DateTime.Now;

var date = ocorrencia.DataOcorrencia.ToString();